# How to get the sum of a count of records (from a previous query)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm fairly new to relatively complex SQL and could use some help with an issue.  I have a query:

```
select
  case 
    when group_id = 'ABC Acme' then 'ABC'
    when group_id like 'Premium%' then 'PREM'
    when group_id like '%Marvel%' then 'MRV'
    else  NULL
  end client, 
  load_date, report_date, count(*) as record_count
from tablename
group by client, load_date, report_date
order by client, load_date;
```

that returns the following:

```
client  load_date   report_date record_count
ABC     4/1/2016    2/28/2016   16108
PREM    4/19/2016   3/31/2017   5348
MRV     4/19/2016   3/31/2017   8335
```

I would like to, if possible, get a sum total of record_count (or 29791). Ideally it would be great to add another row to the results above that has this total. I tried the following query but it didn't work...

```
select
  case 
    when group_id = 'ABC Studios' then 'ABC'
    when group_id like 'Premium%' then 'PREM'
    when group_id like '%Marvel%' then 'MRV'
    else NULL
  end client, 
  load_date, report_date, count (*)
from tablename
  group by client, load_date, report_date
  union all
select 'SUM', count(*)
from tablename;
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
--get summary ttl of counts by load_date for each client
select
case wh...
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: each UNION query must have the same number of columns;
Execution time: 0s
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: The error is clear. If you want `UNION` two queries both need to have same number of columns. What you should include in your question is what is your expected result so we can help you to build the query.

Comment: You are right @JuanCarlosOropeza. I did get explicit answers which helped me address this every issue.  THNXS for jumping in and helping out, it's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support `grouping sets` or `rollup`, which definitely simplifies this.

For maintainability and consistency, I prefer to use a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select (case when group_id = 'ABC Acme' then 'ABC'
                   when group_id like 'Premium%' then 'PREM'
                   when group_id like '%Marvel%' then 'MRV'
              end) as client, 
             load_date, report_date, count(*) as record_count
      from tablename
      group by client, load_date, report_date
     )
select client, load_date, report_date, record_count
from ((select t.*, 1 as priority
       from t
      ) union all
      (select 'SUM', NULL, NULL, sum(record_count), 2
       from t
      )
     ) t
order by priority, client, load_date;
```

Notes:

- By putting any potential filtering conditions or calculation in the CTE, you ensure consistency.
- In practice, databases returns the rows from a `UNION ALL` in order.  But this is not guaranteed.  The explicit use of `priority` column ensures that data is in the right order.
- It is fairly easy to add additional subaggregations.
- `grouping sets` is much preferred.

Comment: Your answer was 100% on point Gordon! I think I will need to pay more attention to CTE. I especially liked your adding the use of "priority" to get the results sorted properly. I can build on this answer and maybe make my query a bit more sophisticated

Answer (score 0):

When you `union` recordsets together, they need to have the same number of columns.  Right now, your 1st query has 4 columns, and the 2nd query only has 2 columns.  Just select `null` for the load_date and the report_date in the 2nd query (those fields are meaningless for the grand total, anyway).

```
select
  case 
    when group_id = 'ABC Studios' then 'ABC'
    when group_id like 'Premium%' then 'PREM'
    when group_id like '%Marvel%' then 'MRV'
  else
    NULL
  end client, load_date, report_date, count (*), 1 priority
  from tablename
  group by client, load_date, report_date

  union all

  select 'SUM', null, null, count(*), 2 priority
  from tablename
  order by priority;
```

Comment: Hi @Jerrad, your answer also worked nicely but I'll need to add a minor modification in order to get the results sorted properly (using a "priority" of sorts). Right now each time I run your solution, I get the summary row appearing at different rowids

Comment: Easy enough to fix.  Just add a priority column to the SELECT.  Give it a value of 1 for the actual data, and 2 for the total row.  Then sorting by that priority puts the total row at the bottom.

Comment: It sure does, THNXS again! This is also a very elegant/simple solution. I can probably play with it a bit and extend it for more ambitious scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can add the extra column for Total records as

```
declare @ttl int;
Set @ttl = (Select Count(*) from tablename)
select
  case 
    when group_id = 'ABC Studios' then 'ABC'
    when group_id like 'Premium%' then 'PREM'
    when group_id like '%Marvel%' then 'MRV'
  else
    NULL
  end client, load_date, report_date, count (*), @ttl AS Sum
  from tablename
  group by client, load_date, report_date
```

Comment: @Jerrad:  Rahul, this solution did not work for me (exactly) but I think it's solely because I'm using Redshift and apparently declaring and using variables there is like pulling teeth. But I like the technique and I think I can incorporate it in a Stored Procedure